# Analysis operator and synthesis operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$\text { Let }\left\{e_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { be an orthonormal sequence for a Hilbert space } H$, let $ T: H \rightarrow \ell^{2}$  be the analysis operator $ T x=\left\{\left\langle x, e_{n}\right\rangle\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $T^{*}: \ell^{2} \rightarrow H $ $ T^{*} c=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} e_{n}$ be the synthesis operator, I was wondering how to find explicit formula for $TT^*$. I have figured out that $T^{*} T=I$, however since $\left\{e_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not complete so it's not clear to me how to find $TT^*$ from $T^*T$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $T^*T = I$ is equivalent to $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ being complete, because then for $x\in H$
$$\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^N\langle x, e_n\rangle e_n \right\}_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$$
is a Cauchy sequence in span$\{e_n\}$ which converges to $x$.

So, generally $T^*T = I$ iff $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is complete. You should also have for $c= \{c_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^2$
$$ TT^*(c) = \left\{\langle \sum_n c_ne_n, e_k\rangle\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} = \left\{c_k\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} = c.$$